# FeathersJS Chat Application Tutorial Gravatar Hook Failure

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

i am doing right now the FeathersJS Chat Application Tutorial, but i am based on Mongoose.

It's all right, i can create user, authenticate and so on, but at the point, i want to implement the gravatar hook i become a failure when i want to start the server.

I have copy & pasted all the code, this is my error when i run the server.

Users.hook.js

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

const { hashPassword, protect } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local').hooks;

const gravatar = require('../../hooks/gravatar');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    get: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    create: [ hashPassword(), gravatar() ],
    update: [ hashPassword(), authenticate('jwt') ],
    patch: [ hashPassword(), authenticate('jwt') ],
    remove: [ authenticate('jwt') ]
  },

  after: {
    all: [ 
      // Make sure the password field is never sent to the client
      // Always must be the last hook
      protect('password')
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Gravatar.js

```
// Use this hook to manipulate incoming or outgoing data.
// For more information on hooks see: http://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html

// We need this to create the MD5 hash
const crypto = require('crypto');

// The Gravatar image service
const gravatarUrl = 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar';
// The size query. Our chat needs 60px images
const query = 's=60';

module.exports = function (options = {}) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  return async context => {
    // The user email
    const { email } = context.data;
    // Gravatar uses MD5 hashes from an email address to get the image
    const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(email).digest('hex');

    context.data.avatar = `${gravatarUrl}/${hash}?${query}`;

    // Best practise, hooks should always return the context
    return context;
  };
};
```

Error

```
    /mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/_coding/feathersJSChat/server/src/hooks/gravatar.js:13
  return async context => {
               ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/_coding/feathersJSChat/server/src/services/users/users.hooks.js:5:18)
```

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the [basics guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/readme.html) the code shown for the chat application will only work with Node 8.0.0 (`node --version`) or later. More information can be found in the [prerequisites seciton](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/setup.html).